# Violin wheezing sound

Tags: violin, sound, beginner, string-instruments

So recently I've started playing the violin, but so far I'm not successful at all. Every time I try to get a sound out of it, all I hear is a high wheezing sound, like someone is trying to catch its breath. I've tried several things, such as a higher pressure on my bow or using rosin/wax. Does anyone have an idea how to troubleshoot this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm slightly concerned at your mention of wax.  Only use rosin.  If it's a new bow or bow with new hair, then you will need to keep applying rosin quite a bit until it is performing correctly.

Comment: Go get it checked by a luthier if yesterday everything is okay, but today is not.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 components to making a nice sound on the violin.

- Contact point
- Bow speed
- Bow pressure

The contact point is whereabouts on the string the bow makes contact. It should be somewhere between the bridge (the light coloured thing that holds the strings up) and the fingerboard (the long dark thing that provides counter pressure when you hold a string down with one of the fingers of the left hand.

For a nice sound first time try a contact point close to the fingerboard on the open D string (don't put any fingers down). Use light pressure. The bow can just rest lightly on the string. Use a fast bow. Start the stroke near the frog (where you are holding the bow) and continue smoothly, quickly and straight to almost the tip.

Once you can make a nice sound on the open D you can experiment with changing the variables. You can try playing closer to the bridge, with less speed and with more bow pressure. You can also try varying the string and the position of your finger. Different combinations are required for different notes on different strings with different finger positions to make a nice sound.